# ISAPI ZEND url rewrite adding extra "/index.php/" into url

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, isapi, httpd.conf, isapi-rewrite

We recently reinstalled our web site on our server, the sys admin says it is an exact rebuild, and it indeed looks to me that it is, but there is something different going on.  I did not originally develop the site, and those who did are no longer available.

urls for the admin site are now

//admin.site.com/index.php/schedules

and used to be, and should be

//admin.site.com/schedules

The extra index.php is getting inserted in the url.  But all links within the admin site do not include the index.php so they do not work.  If you insert the index.php into any url, it works.  Where did this index.php come from and how do I eliminate it from the rewrite rules so the links will work.

This is what my httpd.conf file reads:

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.56

# turn on rewriting RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

# for all files not found in the file system,
# reroute to "index.php" bootstrap script,
# keeping the query string intact. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.site.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.site.com$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement and enable ApacheModrewrite. And then put a .htaccess file in your admin.site.com folder
Its content will be :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d


RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```