# Duplicate 'index.php' using ISAPI to re-write URL on IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-6, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I'm using ISAPI_Rewrite v2 to remove my index.php on IIS 6. This is how the rewrite should work:

```
http://dev.mysite.co.uk/mypage      => http://dev.mysite.co.uk/index.php/mypage
http://dev.mysite.co.uk/anotherpage => http://dev.mysite.co.uk/index.php/anotherpage
```

Using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] I can see that what actually is happening is this:

```
http://dev.mysite.co.uk/mypage      => http://dev.mysite.co.uk/index.php/index.php/mypage
http://dev.mysite.co.uk/anotherpage => http://dev.mysite.co.uk/index.php/index.php/anotherpage
```

This causes a 404 error. The rewrite rules are contained in httpd.ini which is placed in my subdomain's root folder. Here is the rule i'm using:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463152/isapi-zend-url-rewrite-adding-extra-index-php-into-url) which describes the same issue but it has no answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it just loops, so please try to fix it like this:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteRule /(?!index\.php/.*)(.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
```